# What does the date on the tombstone mean?

Tags: europe, austria-hungary

This photo was taken in the Cathedral of St. Martin in Bratislava. I found information about the genus Palffy, but not one of his representatives died in 1845; moreover, it turns out that this person lived 245 years. What exactly does this date mean?
[image: Photo of Palffy's tombstone]

Comment: If Google is right then "család sírboltja" means "family tomb" so this isn't necessarily the resting place of a single individual.

Comment: Perhaps these are the years of the burial of the first and last members of the Palffy family during this period, but I have not found information about them.

Comment: That’s not a tombstone, but a marble cover over a staircase that leads to Palffy’s family crypt where members of the family are burried. If I get the info about the 1845 date I can edit the comment as an answer. It’s probably the date when the crypt was used the last time, but that’s only my speculation.

Comment: 1600 is the year of the death of Nicolas Palffy and 1845 the year of the last ceremony that took place in the crypt. Around 20 members of the family are burried there.

Comment: Probably, your answer is correct. Interesting fact, that Palffy was Hungarians, but buried in Slovakia.

Comment: Slovakia didn’t exist at that time and Bratislava/Pozsony was a capital city (partially) because of Ottoman occupation of Buda. Nor Austria-Hungary (as the question is tagged).